# CSS Color Weirdness

Tags: bug, css

This is a screenshot of a recent answer I wrote on my iPad mini using Chrome. Notice that there are two different shades of the same color in the links: the first two are considerably paler.

[image]

Here, however, is the same text in edit mode, where the colors are now identical:

[image]

Comment: The lighter shade appears after the link has been clicked. This is by design.

Comment: Yes, that's been a standard browser feature since Netscape, but I don't click my own links while composing an answer. That also wouldn't explain why the "visited" color would disappear in edit mode.

Comment: Ahh, whatzitcalled caching or something. Maybe mobile sites are slower to refresh or it's the other way round. Not sure, not an expert.

Comment: I've noticed this on other Stack Exchange sites while using the desktop site.  It's probably this way on all sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the `.post-text` class, to which the "real" post belongs, has a `:visited` pseudo-class for links which alters their colour.

When you are editing, the edited text appears in a `div` of class `wmd-preview`, which does not alter the colour of visited links.

It may be that this feature is by design. It may be that the `wmd-preview` class should alter the colour of visited links, in order that the preview is accurate. I'm not sure it's actually a *bug,* though; or that it's serious enough for developers to fix.

However: well noticed. I hadn't.